# Cannot render view using Ionic

Tags: javascript, ios, view, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic for the first time and I have a little issue. I've read the doc and tutorials but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

First, here is my code (I have started from a blank project).

## The code

app.js (I've just added one state) :

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    }
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

});
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
          <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
      </ion-side-menu-content>

      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="home">
            Home
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>

  </body>
</html>
```

And my view (in `/www/templates/home.html`) :

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content>
        <div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae inventore quod nihil quia, provident porro! Nulla ad libero deserunt, ullam soluta voluptates quidem dolore harum hic consequatur quas suscipit, ab.</div>
            <div>Rerum, eum. Doloribus ullam voluptas repudiandae corrupti ipsa modi magnam, odit perferendis quam reprehenderit sapiente. Rerum impedit sequi voluptatibus porro ducimus dolor animi atque cupiditate similique praesentium. Beatae, suscipit, dolor.</div>
            <div>Quasi natus cupiditate dignissimos non sed quaerat dolorem assumenda minima consectetur, quibusdam nostrum odio molestias voluptate eaque ut fugit atque quia totam laudantium? Repellendus ad, voluptatem itaque ut dolor placeat!</div>
            <div>Quidem illo, molestias pariatur dolor laudantium et doloribus nostrum, hic quae consequuntur, nesciunt explicabo temporibus tempore possimus. Sint dolor, suscipit, iure, dolorem maiores veniam est cum eligendi iusto dolorum praesentium?</div>
            <div>Dicta nihil amet, sapiente deserunt, facilis autem. Est debitis voluptate velit dicta explicabo alias culpa laborum nesciunt mollitia delectus, quos ut eius, itaque qui temporibus laudantium iusto reprehenderit omnis incidunt.</div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

## The issue

Okay so basically, I just want to have one view (and add some other views later). At this point, my home view should be rendered when I serve my app, but both title (nav-bar) and content are **not** displayed. I've tried many things (syntax in my app.js, caches etc). But nothing works.

Do you have an idea ? :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Below I copied your code and I've done these changes:

- introduced an abstract view (app) which manages the structure of side menu (related view is menu.html)
- changed home view to a sub-view of "app"

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  console.log('run');
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  console.log('config');
  $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "menu.html",
    controller: 'AppController'
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "home.html"
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');

})

.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  console.log('AppController');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <title></title>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <!--script src="cordova.js"></script-->
  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  
  <script id="menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
  </script>
  
  <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content>
    <div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae inventore quod nihil quia, provident porro! Nulla ad libero deserunt, ullam soluta voluptates quidem dolore harum hic consequatur quas suscipit, ab.</div>
      <div>Rerum, eum. Doloribus ullam voluptas repudiandae corrupti ipsa modi magnam, odit perferendis quam reprehenderit sapiente. Rerum impedit sequi voluptatibus porro ducimus dolor animi atque cupiditate similique praesentium. Beatae, suscipit, dolor.</div>
      <div>Quasi natus cupiditate dignissimos non sed quaerat dolorem assumenda minima consectetur, quibusdam nostrum odio molestias voluptate eaque ut fugit atque quia totam laudantium? Repellendus ad, voluptatem itaque ut dolor placeat!</div>
      <div>Quidem illo, molestias pariatur dolor laudantium et doloribus nostrum, hic quae consequuntur, nesciunt explicabo temporibus tempore possimus. Sint dolor, suscipit, iure, dolorem maiores veniam est cum eligendi iusto dolorum praesentium?</div>
      <div>Dicta nihil amet, sapiente deserunt, facilis autem. Est debitis voluptate velit dicta explicabo alias culpa laborum nesciunt mollitia delectus, quos ut eius, itaque qui temporibus laudantium iusto reprehenderit omnis incidunt.</div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```